# My recursion of getting subset doesn't print out the right answer

Tags: algorithm, recursion, combinations, subset

I am trying to implement a method to get all subset of a set. I understand the logic of doing that. i.e. Subset(n) = n + Subset(n-1), but the code I wrote keep printing out the wrong answers. Here is my code:

```
void subset(vector<int> &input, vector<int> output, int current) {
    if (current == input.size()-1) {
        output.push_back(input[current]);
        print(output);
    }
    else {
        for (int i = current; i < input.size();i++) {
            output.push_back(input[i]);
            print(output);
            subset(input, output, i+1);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the output I got (input is {1,2,3}):

```
1 
1 2 
1 2 3 
1 2 3 
1 2 
1 2 3 
1 2 3
```

Any idea where I went wrong? Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this can help you:

```cpp
void subset(vector<int> &input, vector<int> output, int current) {
    static int n=0;
    if (current == input.size()) {
        cout<<n++<<":\t {";
        for(int i=0;i<output.size();i++) cout<<output[i]<<", ";
        cout<<"\b\b}\n";
    }
    else {
        subset(input, output, current+1); //exclude current'th item
        output.push_back(input[current]);
        subset(input, output, current+1); //include current'th item 
    }
}
```

and first time you may call it like this:

```cpp
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> inp, out;
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++) // for example {1,2,3,4,5}
        inp.push_back(i);
    subset(inp, out, 0);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- You always print the output from its beginning: therefore you would never see [2,3], or [2] or [3] in the output
- You have print statements in two places - thus the duplication of outputs